# How do fighter ships in the Dark Matter supplement communicate with each other?

Tags: dnd-5e, vehicles, science-fiction

I was looking through the *Dark Matter* supplement for 5th Edition D&D by Mage Hand Press ([Kickstarter with sample PDF](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/magehandpress/dark-matter-2); [store page](https://store.magehandpress.com/products/dark-matter-alpha)) to find out what the fewest-in-common Ship Systems were, when I noticed that all fighter-class ships (excepting the Lakshayan Ashigaru Frame) lacked a Communications system.

As stated under "Communications" in the "Systems" section, "for two ships to communicate, they must both have a functioning Communications system and be within 1,000 miles of one another". Try as I might, I cannot find any mention of how ships without such systems could communicate.

Does this mean that fighter ships cannot communicate with its allies, even other fighter ships? I have been looking through the book and, to my knowledge, it does not seem fighter ships can. There are items in the supplement which could be used, such as comm sets and relay stations, but even then, comm sets are stated to only reach up to 1 mile, and are blocked by "1 foot of stone, 1 inch of common metal, a thin sheet of lead, or 3 feet of wood or dirt".

**How do fighter ships in the *Dark Matter* supplement communicate with each other and their other allies? Are they unable to communicate with other ships, as it seems?**

P.S. I realize posting this question here is very much a shot in the dark, considering I couldn't even tag it properly, but I could not find any discussion of the supplement elsewhere. Please comment if you do know of a dedicated forum!

Comment: Shout out to Dark Matter!  FYI Mage Hand Press has a Discord channel where a lot of questions are answered. https://mfov.magehandpress.com/2018/09/mage-hand-press-discord.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I posed this question on Mage Hand Press's Discord channel, I received the following responses from the game developers:

> "damn, I think that's an error on our part I don't think we put in any
>   provision to allow fighters to communicate, which they obviously need
>   to be able to do My instinct would be to make a specific thing that
>   fighters can communicate with their mothership as long as the
>   mothership's Communicator system is working"
>   -The Nails of Vecna

and

> "it looks like an accidental ommission. I'll go through and add
>   Communications to fighters" -The Finger of Vecna

Comment: That's great, thanks!